# Connect button grayed out in 802.1x authentication dialog

Tags: wireless, network-manager, security

Since I upgraded to 15.04 I can't connect to our office wired network anymore since I can't press connect in the authentication dialog.

[image]

Comment: ha! Could you please `killall nm-applet`, start `nm-applet` from a terminal and report the output you get when reproducing. There is bound to be an error.

Comment: I got this in the terminal 
** (nm-connection-editor:5708): WARNING **: Invalid setting 802.1x Security: Invalid 802.1x security
I then removed 802.1x security and added it back and this time I could save the password in the settings. That got it working. So solved for now but in a different way. I will reopen if I get the issue back

Comment: Relevant: http://askubuntu.com/questions/323348/why-is-the-connect-button-greyed-out-when-entering-the-wifi-password-for-wirel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To try to solve my issue I removed the 802.1x security in the connection settings. When I then added it back I was able to save the password in the settings. That got it working.

Answer (score 3):

Came across this issue as well on 15.04. Same symptoms and errors as OP but killing/re-starting the nm-applet wouldn't fix anything.

The solution for me was to edit the configuration file for my network interface located at

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired\ connection\ 1
```

I added the relevant parts of my 802.1x settings in the file and it allowed me to connect. So, something like this:

```
[802-1x]
eap=peap;
identity=username
phase2-auth=mschapv2
```